# Regexp to convert tags (similar to BBCode) to HTML

Tags: ruby, regex, bbcode, gsub

I have set of strings with nested `[quote]` tags in following format:

```
[quote name="John"]Some text. [quote name="Piter"]Inner quote.[/quote][/quote]
```

As you see it is not like ordinary BBCode. So I can't find a suitable regexp for `gsub` in Ruby to convert them to strings like this:

```
<blockquote>
  <p>Some text. 

    <blockquote>
      <p>Inner quote.</p>
      <small>Piter</small>
    </blockquote>
  </p>
  <small>John</small>
</blockquote>
```

Can anybody please help me with such regexp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that regexes fundamentally can't cope with nesting. What you could do is make it do a minimal match (e.g. only the inner quote levels), replace them, and then repeat as long as you have more matches. Once you've replaced a level it will just be HTML so will not match the regex any more.